# Asp.NET MVC - Combining Two Project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, solution, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have two different mvc (and it's own layers) project in a solution. I decided to combine these project, these will have same layout, contents etc. But, I also want to keep layers seperately.

So, should I open an area for project2 in project1 or can I configure the project2 to like www.project1.com/project2 without touching project file. In second case, I think I should copy my contents and layout stuffs from project1 to project2.

This question waiting for advice from you. Thank you...
[image: Solution Folders]

Comment: Couldn't you just create a reference to the `PLM.UI.Web` project from the `Assessment.MVCWebUI` project, then have `using SolutionName.SupportPortal.PLM.UI.Web` in the required controller? Or am I completely out in the wild here?